# Mui Theme Use Primary Color

Tags: material-ui

So I want to create an outline on my button that the outline color uses the primary color but not sure how you can reference the primary color.

```js
export const BaseTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        ‘&:focus’: {
          outline: ‘2px solid primaryColorHere’
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So how can I set the primary color? Does MUI have a way to reference this?

Solution:

So it appears that I can use a function as a value which will give me access to a theme variable that I can set

```js
export const BaseTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: ({ theme }) => ({
        ‘&:focus’: {
          outline: ‘2px solid $(theme.palette.primary.main)’
        }
      }),
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ### Providing the colors directly
>
> If you wish to provide more customized colors, you can either create your own palette color, or directly supply colors to some or all of the theme.palette keys:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // Provide every color token (light, main, dark, and contrastText) when using
    // custom colors for props in Material UI's components.
    // Then you will be able to use it like this: `<Button color="custom">`
    // (For TypeScript, you need to add module augmentation for the `custom` value)
    custom: {
      light: '#ffa726',
      main: '#f57c00',
      dark: '#ef6c00',
      contrastText: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    },
    // Used by `getContrastText()` to maximize the contrast between
    // the background and the text.
    contrastThreshold: 3,
    // Used by the functions below to shift a color's luminance by approximately
    // two indexes within its tonal palette.
    // E.g., shift from Red 500 to Red 300 or Red 700.
    tonalOffset: 0.2,
  },
});
```

Then you can access it this way:

```js
//...
'&:focus': {
  outline: `2px solid ${theme => theme.palette.primary.main}`
}
```

Don't forget to provide the theme to your app:

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
//...
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   //...
</ThemeProvider>
```

[docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/).

Comment: Where is that theme object coming from since I am creating my theme object in my code above? Or in compile time it will pick that theme object up?

Comment: No you create a theme apart as shown in the answer then you provide it to all the app then you can access it from anywhere to pick the element you want

Comment: Ah my issue is not using the theme. I understand that one. What I want is in my theme I want to access primary color. I was hoping that not every user would have to do what you put.

Comment: Where your primary color is stored ?

Comment: I just figured it out. Change the value of `root` to a function which passes in the theme object.

root: ({theme}) => ({})

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean